# Can a macro in Google Sheets add numbers to different lists of different lengths, on the same Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to add numbers to lists on the same sheet but each list might be of a different length.

I have created an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsUfXQbzyh-dR8hf_66UDBie9MgHOoFUVgGs5iNV6s8/edit?usp=sharing

So each list would need to have the relevant number list to the LHS side of each list.

I would want the one macro to populate the 3 lists of numbers in one go.

Have not been able to find a way of getting the to work.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `So each list would need to have the relevant number list to the LHS side of each list. I would want the one macro to populate the 3 lists of numbers in one go.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: those lists don't have numbers they have words?

Comment: I have added a list of numbers to the LHS of the first word list.  I would want the other 2 lists to be numbered in the same way but to a larger last number because those lists are longer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign sequence numbers to lists of words.

To use this answer, select the first word in a list then run the script.

NB: The script assumes that there are **no gaps** in the list

---

```
function numberList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // get the current selected cell
  var selection = ss.getSelection()
  var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell()
  // Returns values for the current highlighted cell
  var currentSheet = currentCell.getSheet()
  var currentRow = currentCell.getRow()
  var currentColumn = currentCell.getColumn()
  var colLastRow = currentCell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()
  var dataRange = currentSheet.getRange(currentRow,currentColumn,(colLastRow-currentRow+1))

  // create tempArray for sequence numbers
  // assign sequence numbers to array
  var seqNumArray = new Array
  for (var i=0;i<(colLastRow-currentRow+1);i++){
    seqNumArray.push([(i+1)])
  }
  
  // paste the sequence nuymbers to the sheet
  dataRange.offset(0,-1).setValues(seqNumArray)

}
```

---

**SAMPLE**

[image]